# Advanced syntax search on angular 4

Tags: angular, search

I wanted to build a search mechanism like Pocket has.
They use several syntax for that;
https://help.getpocket.com/article/894-pocket-premium-full-text-search

I can make it like;

> foo (+title:bar)

But if i wanted to search a title with space in it, Pocket use quotes for that.

What i really want is to remove the parentheses and make a search like this;

> foo +title:"hello world"

Does anyone knows how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the **Elastic search**. It offers a tonne of features and is also very fast.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my problem is understanding the syntax written by a user. Otherwise server side operations are fairly simple.